# Como se podría multiplicar un valor por algun valor del arraylist en java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Soy nuevo en java y apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar arraylist. 
Mi pregunta es si se podria por ejemplo multiplicar 2 por la posicion 1 del arraylist que supongamos que es 3.

Comment: Hola bienvenido al sitio Alexander, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio. Es algo que podrías investigar y si te trabas preguntas acá donde encontraste la dificultad. [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Si se puede multiplicar un valor por la posición de un array..

Answer (score 1):

si se puede, me imagino que ya sabes como crear y agregar items a un array, sino:

```js
ArrayList<int> nombreArrayList = new ArrayList<int>();
// Añade el elemento al ArrayList
nombreArrayList.add(3);
nombreArrayList.add(4);
nombreArrayList.add(7);
```

Después puedes declarar dos variables y hacer lo siguiente:

```js
int total = 0;
int x = 2;
total = x * nombreArrayList[1];
```

Lo que hago básicamente acá es decirle que guarde en la variable **total** el resultado de la multiplicación de **2** por el valor que se encuentre en la posición 1 de **NombreArrayList** que para este caso es 4.

Ojala esto te ayude, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el código de lo que necesitas:

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

 public static final String cadena = "cadena";
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  numeros.add(4);
  numeros.add(10);
  numeros.add(2);
  numeros.add(92);
  
  int posicion = 2; // Recuerda que un array se empieza a contar desde el 0, por lo que el tercer numero corresponderia al 2
  int resultado = 2 * numeros.get(posicion);
  System.out.println(resultado);
 }
}
```

En primer lugar, no puedes crear un ArrayList del tipo primitivo int, pero si del wrapper Integer. Integer es una clase de Java que además de guardar el número como int, contiene funciones para hacer con el número.

Luego, un ArrayList funciona igual que un objeto del tipo List. Un array sería algo más puro de la informática, más antiguo, digamos, pero no menos válido o más inútil, en absoluto.

Como ves, para acceder al elemento en cuestión no sería como en un array, que sería array[posicion]...En un ArrayList sería array.get(posicion), ya que un ArrayList no es más que una clase, mientras que un array es algo más primitivo que ésto.